# How to extend/increase ubuntu disk space on a dual boot win7/ubuntu 12.4

Tags: 12.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-7

I have installed Windows 7 and ubuntu 12.04 as dual boot on my 320 GB laptop. 
I have three partitions. 
200 GB - Window's 7 is installed in it. 
100 GB - NTFS partition (un used). 
20 GB - Ubuntu 12.04.

I can access 100 GB (new volume) both in windows and ubuntu 12.04.

I am running out of ubuntu disk space. How can I extend/increase 20 GB to 120 GB by using  100 GB(unused) disk space?

Answer (score 1):

If the 100 GB partition is contiguous with the 20 GB partition, then you can do this fairly easily:

Boot from a live CD/USB

open a terminal <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>

get gparted

`sudo apt-get install gparted`

run gparted, and choose to resize your Ubuntu partition.

If the free space is not contiguous with the Ubuntu partition, you may need to move things about a bit.

Before you do these things, make a backup of both of your systems - there's always a possibility of things going awry, and Windows does not like to have it's partitions messed about with very much.

Comment: what kind of live CD/USB do you recommend?

Comment: I think that the minimum size USB has to be 4 GB, and I use standard DVD's for boot purposes.  I have had occasional trouble with some USB devices, but I have quite a few of the smaller devices lying around and just pick another.

Comment: @[Charles Green] Could we not run the gparted from inside the ubuntu which is installed? What issue could it cause ?